# Run and Debug unit tests with flags

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve, gopls

I want to be able to run and debug unit tests within VS Code using the test explorer or code lens.
But in order to run my tests, I need to add this flag:

```
-ldflags "-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn"
```

Therefore, in my vscode settings.json file, I have added this json:

```
"go.testFlags": [        
    "-ldflags",
    "\"-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn\""
]
```

Now when I click the Run Test button in test explorer or in the code lens, VS Code generates this command:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestCreateNamespace$ github.com/SomePath/SomeRepo/internal/models/v2 -ldflags "-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn"
```

but the test case fails with this error:

```
panic: proto: extension number 1042 is already registered on message google.protobuf.FileOptions
See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict
```

And this is the exact error that I am expecting if I dont suply the `-ldflags` in my go test command. But the surprising thing is that when I copy the exact same vs code generated test command mentioned above and run that in my terminal then the test case passes.
Along with running the tests from Vs Code, I would also like to be able to debug them by setting breakpoints and stepping through code.

**Dev Environment:** I am on an arm64 apple M1 Mac if that matters.

**UPDATE**: After fiddling around with the `go.testFlags` values, I have found that:

1. This configuration works for vs code `run test` functionality:

```
"go.testFlags": [        
    "-ldflags",
    "-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn"
]
```

2. This configuration works for vs code `debug test` functionality:

```
"go.testFlags": [        
    "-ldflags",
    "'-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn'"
]
```

(Notice the extra single quotes in debug configuration).

Now I need to find a single configuration that works for both `run test` as well as `debug test` functionalities, Or somehow specify 2 different configs for `run test` and `debug test` in `settings.json` file of vs code so that I can use both functionalities without making changes to the `settings.json` file every-time. (This might be a delve thing I suspect)

Comment: Does Code use the same shell and the same environment as your terminal?
Have you tried using `'` (single-quote) instead of double-quote?

Comment: @mehdy your suggestion of using single quotes has helped me solve this partially, I've updated the question with my findings.

Comment: Got it. Posted an answer. let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for VS Code, but when it comes to debugging tests that are a bit more complex to step through (e.g. godog cucumber-style tests) I usually compile the test binary like so:

```
go test -c -gcflags="all=-N -l"
```

You can replace `go test -c` with `go build`, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to simply use

```
go test -c -ldflags "-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn" -gcflags="all=-N -l"
```

Then, you can start a `dlv` session in headless mode for your editor to connect to. Let's say `go test -c` generated a binary called *"foo.test"*:

```
dlv exec ./foo.test  --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2    -- -count=1 -- $(pwd)/some/path
```

where `-count=1` is a placeholder for the flags you would normally pass to `go test`, and `-- $(pwd)/some/path` could be (in case you have cucumber style tests) a path to a `.feature` file. You can now connect your editor to the dlv session and start debugging. Asking some of my colleagues how that works in VSCode, they said something about a command palette and running `Debug: Open launch.json`, which should look something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Test",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "showLog":true,
            "trace":"log"
        }
    ]
}
```

Set the breakpoints, and you should be able to open the debug panel and run `Debug test`.

---

In case anyone wonders, the flow for Vim is pretty much the same, except that there is no need for a json file. Using the `vim-go` plugin, once the dlv session is running, you set your breakpoints (`:GoDebugBreakpoint`), and connect to dlv: `:GoDebugConnect 127.0.0.1:2345`.

From that point on, it's pretty much the same as any debug session `:GoDebugContinue`, `:GoDebugStep`, `:GoDebugStepOut`, `:GoDebugPrint varname` and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```yaml
"go.testFlags": [        
    "-ldflags",
    "-X",
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn"
]
```

When you create new tasks in VSCode you need to write each space-separated word/character as different parameters.

Comment: tried it, but it generates the wrong command. getting this error after trying this solution: `-X flag requires argument of the form importpath.name=value`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Launch Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) instead of making changes in `settings.json`.

So you need to create a file at `.vscode/launch.json` as instructed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) and add the following line to the file:

```json
"buildFlags": "-ldflags='-X google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry.conflictPolicy=warn'",
```

It seems to work for both running and debugging the project.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved by setting env vars in `settings.json` like this:

```
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {
        "GOLANG_PROTOBUF_REGISTRATION_CONFLICT": "warn"
    },
```