# Run go test with `-v` in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, testing

I need to see the output from `t.Infof()`, is it possible to run go test with `-v` in vscode?

The `Run test` button does not add the `-v` parameter, what should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe VSCode has a settings.json file where you can add the following:

```
"go.testFlags": ["-v"]
```

which should pass the `-v` flag to `go test`.

Note that I'm not a VSCode user, but based on [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647814/run-and-debug-unit-tests-with-flags) I remember answering, that should be the way to go.

Alternatively, I believe VSCode does have an integrated terminal, so I'd probably just use that to be able to quickly run things like `go test -v -failfast -count=1 path/to/pkg... -run TestFooCaseA` without faffing around with json config files :)